# Bxslider Image has wrong width/height on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using a bxslider for a website.

When the website loads, the image has weird width/height and the load seems weird.

You can see it live at:
http://adamskymotorkylare.se/

You can see the css used for the slider in the slider css file and the javascript at the bottom of the page, at "Delay Load". (With source) + the document write section.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or why the error appears? (To get the image error, just reload the page.)

Video of error:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxzf3cFn9Sk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Don't see any errors or weird image. Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Reload the URL quickly. Multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately using my phone at the moment, cant take screen shoots that fast. Will try to upload video.

Comment: See video in description =)

Comment: I can see on mobile you give the img a specific height and width wich is not respecting the img aspect ratio. Using bx slider can be tricky sometimes, however you may want to use the 'adaptiveHeight: true,' and also just give the image a width: 100%. This may not be the answer but you may want to give it a try.

Comment: I Will give it a go, thank you